# Customize header in class scrreport with fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

In the example below a header is displayed on each page with a line underneath it. How can I get rid of it and italicize the header?

```
\documentclass[
  french,
  ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lastpage}
%\usepackage{scrpage2} % Error: \chead already defined
\usepackage{xwatermark} % needed

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{The header}
\cfoot{\thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}
%\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
%\pagestyle{headings} % no headings displayed


\begin{document}

FOO

\newpage

BAR

\end{document}
```

Comment: Like this: `\chead{\textit{The header}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the line underneath the header, you can use `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}`.

To italicize the header you can use `\textit`

```
\documentclass[
  french,
  ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lastpage}
%\usepackage{scrpage2} % Error: \chead already defined
\usepackage{xwatermark} % needed

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\chead{\textit{The header}}
\cfoot{\thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\pagestyle{headings} % no headings displayed


\begin{document}

FOO

\newpage

BAR

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The culprit here is that you are using package `xwatermark`. It loads package `fancyhdr` and therefore you have to use it in your document. Usually KOMA-Script classes like `scrreprt` uses better the KOMA-Script own package `scrlayer-scrpage`.

To get rid of the headerrule use

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

in your preamble. To get the header in italic use `\textit{}` in the header definition of `fanvyhdr`:

```
\chead{\textit{The header}}
```

With the following complete code

```
\documentclass[%
  french,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{xwatermark} % needed, loads fancyhdr :-(( <=================
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\textit{The header}} % <=========================================
\cfoot{\thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % <==================================


\begin{document}

FOO

\newpage

BAR

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: result]